# Limitar caracteres e exibir a quantidade de caracteres

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Bom galera tenho um `input` para o usuário colocar o nome, e embaixo do input tenho o tanto de caracteres digitados e a quantidade máxima(0/50).
Queria que cade vez que ele digita-se aumenta-se os caracteres digitados e quando atingir o limite não poder mais digitar.

E também quando apagar um caractere diminuir os caracteres digitados...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma forma bem prática é primeiramente colocar um `maxlength="50"` no campo para limitar o número de caracteres e o script abaixo para alterar o contador contabilizando a quantidade de caracteres digitados:

```js
document.querySelector("input[name='nome']") // seleciona o campo pelo atributo "name"
.addEventListener("input", function(){ // evento "input" que detecta mudança de valor no campo
   var cars = this.value.length; //conta a quantidade de caracteres
   // se for menor ou igual a 50, altera texto com o valor no span
   if(cars <= 50) document.querySelector(".limite").textContent = cars;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="nome" maxlength="50">
<span class="limite">0</span>/50
```

Comment: Não tinha visto o PHP

Comment: Blz, não esqueça de marcar ✔, isso é muito importante para o site.

Answer (score 0):

Olá, é bem simples fazer isso

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
    $('#iddocampo').keyup(function(){// evento jquery quando o cara digita

        var campo = $("#iddocampo").val();
        var qtde = campo.length;// max characteres
    });
});
```

Você pode usar também no input maxlength="50" onkeypress="return funcaoJS()"

```
function funcaoJS(){
     var qtde = document.getElementById("iddocampo").value.length;
}
```